POST method with respective inherited class
How can I save a Meal expense within the method?
The way to identify it is as follows in the service (expenses.service.ts) but when I tried to save it will save like a Expense (Parent Entity).
async create(expense: ExpenseDto) { 
    let newExpense = new Meal();
    newExpense.lunch = (expense as Meal).lunch;

    await this.expenseRepository.save(newExpense);
    return this.expenseRepository.findOne({where: { id: newExpense.id },});
}

I have this entities and his respectives Dto's.
@Entity({ name: 'expenses' })
@TableInheritance({
    column: {
        type: 'varchar',
        name: 'expense_type',
    },
})
export class Expense {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    ...
    ...
}

@ChildEntity()
export class Meal extends Expense {
    @Column({ default: true })
    lunch: boolean;
}

The problem is, whenever I go to save, it will save as an Expense (according to the parameter I set) and not as a Meal.
With this input:
{
    ...
    "expenseType": "MEAL",
    "lunch": false
}

the output will always be something like that.
{
    "expenseType": "DEFAULT"
}

I tried within the method to check the type of expense according to the ExpenseType variable (which is filled with an Enum with the existing types) and from there allocate the respective data from the child entity. when I save, it always saves as if it were the parent entity.

I believe you're facing that saving issue because you're using the @ChildEntity annotation. From the docs,

TypeORM also supports single table inheritance. Single table inheritance is a pattern when you have multiple classes with their own properties, but in the database they are stored in the same table.

